# How to use the Wordpress Shortlink (having post ID only) in tweets

Tags: wordpress, url, twitter

Scenario: The urls and titles of the posts on my blog are usually very long. Whenever I or anyone else tweets the post, I don't find any space to add the hashtags or quoted retweet text. I don't want to shorten the titles of the posts, so the other option is to shorten the url. For this purpose I want to grab the shortlink from wordpress post in this format

http://mydomain.com/?p=(post ID)

Can you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Use wp get shortlink

Returns URL based on numerical ID, i.e. http://example.com/?p=1234

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_shortlink

Usage
`<?php $short_link = wp_get_shortlink(); ?>` 
or
`<?php echo wp_get_shortlink(); ?>`

Source File
wp_get_shortlink() is located in wp-includes/link-template.php.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to **Settings -> Permalinks** and set  it to 'default' (or 'numeric' if you prefer) and then call

```
<?php the_permalink() ?>
```

in your “tweet this” link.

or you can use this: [Twitter Friendly Links WordPress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-friendly-links/)

Comment: I don't want to use any plugin. In fact I have been doing the same without needing any plugin. But I have forgot the actual code.

Comment: Ok. you can find many code on internet to shorten your url and make your custom shortener with wordpress (you can use shorten url maker such as bit.ly). but if you want a simpe one, on wordpress, just go to Settings -> Permalinks and choose 'default' or 'numeric' setting. also you can set 'Custom' and put this : '[http://domain.com/?p=post_id]'